# Batch script for creating tasks?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, batch, shell-script, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to create a batch script to add tasks to the Windows Task system? I need to setup 2-3 tasks per system but I want to be able to run a script to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`at.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490866.aspx) program can be used:

```
at /?
```